# Azure b2c logout all apps on logout (Single Sign Out)

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I have an SSO app (Lets say apps A and B) using Azure AD B2C each with react SPAs using `@azure/msal-react` to manage the authentication. In the Azure console, I have both A and B configured with a sign out url (see below)[image]

However when I logout from app A it doesn't automatically log out from app B as expected. Instead app B remains signed in for the current tab, but if I open app B in a second tab its logged out as expected. When I dug deeper I found that some state is left behind in session state for app B. This makes perfect sense as what I believe happens is that the signout link from app B is opened in an iframe in the background. An iframe is a new session so the session storage cant be cleared. [image]

**Is there a way of clearing the data or getting b2c not to use session storage so that logout will work across multiple sites?** I realise I could probably solve this by closing the current tab on logout but it seems like a last resort to me.

Comment: You can tell MSAL.js to use local storage instead of session storage. Would that work?

Comment: @juunas yeah I think that would work well and I would much prefer that anyway, i dont like different tabs having different credential sets. How do you tell MSAL to use local?

Comment: Ah I found the docs, https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/configuration.md#cache-config-options

Comment: arghh, the setting is there but it straight up doesnt work... https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/4231. @juunas do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Trying the same but for angular app and it seems either front channel logout url is not hit at all or this logoutRedirect() does nothing... Sample for angular is hosted here - https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-angular-v2-samples/angular11-sample-app copied almost everything from it and still no luck...

Comment: @rosko yeah I think that single sign out is totally broken, I was able to hack a working solution by using single sign on to detect if the app has been logged out globally, and then execute a client side sign out, but its ugly. Its pretty disappointing that its so badly broken out of the box.

Comment: @undefined do you use basic user flow or custom one? I may try as a last resort and implement the custom but in documentation I can't see anything that says it works only with them so... yeah. A lot of documentation, a lot of examples, samples etc. and in the end it doesn't work...:)

Comment: I did everything in a custom user flow and I can admit that now SLO works correctly. Couldn't achieve that with built-in user flow.

Comment: @rosko im in a custom flow, but the problem I have is pretty fundamental, when the site passes back all of the individual sign out urls each is opened in an iframe in the current page. Because the login store is using session state these iframes get their own session stores so clearing the login state wont actually clear it in the parent tab or any parallel tabs.

Comment: @undefined you should then use `localStorage` instead of `sessionStorage`. I'm pretty sure you won't achieve SLO with cache location set to session.

Comment: @rosko It straight up doesnt work when you change that setting https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/4231

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont at all like this solution but given that single sign out doesnt work properly otherwise here we go:

I solved this by abusing the ssoSilent method, which returns an exception if the user is not logged in. By calling ssoSilent when the user is logged in locally and then checking for that exception we can detect that the user should be signed out.

However ssoSilent puts the site into interaction mode when you initiate an ssoSilent call when the user is logged in locally but out globally. This mode is stored in the mdal.interactions.status cookie, which I delete in order to allow a local sign out.

```
instance.ssoSilent({...})
  .catch((err)=>{
    if(accounts[0] && err instanceof InteractionRequiredAuthError){
      //this is a particularly dirty hack but doing this does give single sign out behavior that closes all sessions.
      document.cookie = 'msal.interaction.status=; Max-Age=0';
      instance.logout();
    }
  });
```